# Question on xmlns for Xml file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I post the question for I don't understand the keywords of `xmlns`, `xmlns:xsd` and `xmlns:xsi`.

I find an example for XpathNavigator `MoveToChile` method as this, attached the xml file sample as well.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("contosoBooks.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

navigator.MoveToChild("bookstore", "http://www.contoso.com/books");
```

The sample Xml file from MSDN.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bookstore xmlns="http://www.contoso.com/books">
    <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">
        <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
        <author>
```

Can you please describe the the difference for `xmlns`, `xmlns:xsd` and `xmlns:xsi`. What can I used to replace `http://www.contoso.com/books` in my case? or I can just insert another xmlns like `xmlns="http://www.mycase.com"`?

Or I don't need include the URL simply. a little like this `navigator.MoveToChild("bookstore", "");`

My xml file as this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Equipment xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <License licenseId="" licensePath=""/>
```

Appreciated for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial on XML namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Basically, you define a **prefix** for your XML namespace to make it easier to use:

```
<Equipment 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <License licenseId="" licensePath=""/>
   <xsd:element ..... xsi:nil="true" />
```

Those elements that belong into the **default** namespace are probably those that you need the most, so you can define one XML namespace without a prefix - the default namespace:

```
<Equipment 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://www.yourcompany.com/your/default/namespace" >
   <License licenseId="" licensePath=""/>
   <xsd:element ..... xsi:nil="true" />
```

Now, all the elements in your XML without a specific prefix (here: the `<License>` tag) are part of your **default** XML namespace.